# how to delete a record from a file in c programming (only one file)

Tags: file, binary

I want to delete a record from my binary file, but I can't use two files because the only parameters I'm passing are the FILE to write and the key to erase an specific record.

The record is just a typedef struct.

Answer (score 0):

If it will fit in memory:

- Buffer entire file in memory
- Truncate the file to 0 bytes
- Write up to just before the start of the record
- Write from just after the end of the record, to the end of the buffer

This assumes the file is not structured with a map or index or chain of pointers to the records.  If those are true you must do more work to delete the data but keep the file structure valid.

BUT you then also have the option of just removing the record from that map while leaving the rest of the file alone (and maybe storing 0....0 at the record location)